# Grammar explanation for ~よし

Tags: grammar

Studying for the N1 with sample questions I stumbled across this grammar construct `~よし`.　However I am unable to find any explanation online or in any of my grammar books - probably I am searching for the wrong expression, but maybe anyone here can help.

Here are a few sample questions, that I could not answer so far:

> 「この夏、定年退職なさった（と・の・との）よし。長い間、お疲れ様でございました。」
>   This summer, I will reach the age for retirement (?). Thanks for taking care of me for so long.
>
> 「来月、日本にいらっしゃる（よし・べし）。ぜひ、お会いしたいですね。」
>   Next month I will be in Japan (?). I definitely want to meet you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, this 「よし」 is 「由」 in kanji.  (It has nothing to do with 「良{よ}し」 meaning "good".)

All by itself, 「由」 means "reason", "circumstances", etc.  Notice the kanji 「由」 is surely used in the word 「理由{りゆう}」 ("reason").

「由{よし}」 is most often used in **formal or business** letters in the form of:

> 「Mini-Sentence + （との） + 由」

meaning:

> "I hear that [Mini-Sentence], (so I am replying.)"

This pattern is rarely, if ever, used in informal letters/emails between two young friends.

> 「この夏、定年退職なさった（と・の・との）よし。長い間、お疲れ様でございました。」 This summer, I will reach the age for retirement (?). Thanks for taking care of me for so long.

It is **not** the writer who has retired.  It is the receiver of this letter.  「なさった」 is honorific.

"I hear that you have retired this summer."

> 「来月、日本にいらっしゃる（よし・べし）。ぜひ、お会いしたいですね。」 Next month I will be in Japan (?). I definitely want to meet you.

It is **not** the writer who is coming to Japan.  The writer is already in Japan.

You would not use the honorific 「いらっしゃる」 to talk about your own action.